# Run script in document load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dialog in jQuery and I want to show the dialog when the document loads. But I don't want to put code in `<body onload="showdialog();">`. I want to put javascript in the main div or the footer div that works like `onload` in the body event. Any way to do this?

```
<body onload="$('#dialog').slideDown('slow');">
  <div id="dialog">Dialog</div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

I want this:

```
<body>
  <div id="dialog">Dialog</div>
  <script> show dialog code in load page </script>
  <footer>
    // or this place =>
    <script> show dialog code in load page </script>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: That is the purpose of `$(document).ready()`. Put it wherever you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to take a look at the ready function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').slideDown('slow');
});
```